# Reverse words in a sentence - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string

How to perform reversing of all words in a sentence.

Example

```
let str = "Hello playground"
```

Result should be like `"olleH dnuorgyalp"`

**With minimum complexity.**

Comment: When you say minimum complexity, do you mean minimum time complexity? Functional programming style is clean and easy to follow, but analyzing time complexity can be tricky because the compiler does a lot of optimization "under the covers"

Answer (score 6):

Here's the typical functional programming approach (also posted by *@Saranjith*)

```
let result = str
    .components(separatedBy: " ")
    .map { $0.reversed() }
    .joined()
```

### Complexity

First of all lets define

- `n`: the number of characters in the input string
- `k`: the number of words in the input string (of course k<=n)

### ⏳ Time complexity

Now lets look at the time complexity of each piece of our code

> **.components(separatedBy: " ")**

This instructions need to go through the entire string so `O(n)`

> **.map { $0.reversed() }**

Here each word is reversed. So if we have `k` words we have a time complexity of

```
O(m0) + O(m1) + ... + O(mk-1)
```

where `mi` is the length of the `i-th` word.
However the sum of the length of all the words is <= n so we can say that

```
O(m0) + O(m1) + ... + O(mk-1) <= O(n)
```

> **.joined()**

Finally we have `k` words which need to be joined togheter. This can be done in `O(k)` that, again, is `<= O(n)`.

**Wrap up**

```
let result = str
    .components(separatedBy: " ") // O(n)
    .map { $0.reversed() } // O(m0) + O(m1) + ... + O(mk-1) <= O(n)
    .joined() // O(k) <= O(n)
```

**Time complexity = O(n) + O(n) + O(n) = O(n)**

### Space complexity

> **.components(separatedBy: " ")**

Here we are building `k Strings (m0, m1, ..., mk-1)`. The sum of the length of these `k-1` words will be `<= n` so here space complexity is `O(n)`.

> **.map { $0.reversed() }**

For each (m0, m1, ..., mk-1) we are building a duplicate. So, again, `O(n)`.

> **.joined()**

Here we are building the result which is a string with n chars. So space complexity is O(n).

**Space complexity: O(n) + O(n) + O(n) = O(n).**

Comment: Good analysis. (Voted). Better performance than I would have thought at first glance. You might be able to get the constant multiplier on the 3•O(n) time complexity down to 1 or 2 with a hand-written loop through the characters, but that's not significant savings.

Comment: @DuncanC Thank you. I agree with your comment about the constant multiplier.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm failing to understand how .map { $0.reversed() } is O(n) because a map is basically a for loop , and that's O(n). And inside of that for loop , you have reversed function which is O(n). Basically a nested for loop which would get you O(n^2). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `String` method `enumerateSubstrings` using `.byWords` options and replace the subrange of each word with the substring reversed. Note that this way the punctuation will remain in place:

---

```
import Foundation
```

Mutating approach:

```
var str = "Hello, playground!!!"

str.enumerateSubstrings(in: str.startIndex..., options: .byWords) { _, range, _, _ in
    str.replaceSubrange(range, with: str[range].reversed())
}
print(str)  // "olleH, dnuorgyalp!!!"
```

---

Non mutating:

```
let str = "Hello, playground!!!"
var result = ""
str.enumerateSubstrings(in: str.startIndex..., options: .byWords) { string, range, enclosingRange, _ in
    result.append(contentsOf: string!.reversed())
    result.append(contentsOf: str[range.upperBound..<enclosingRange.upperBound])
}
print(result)  // "olleH, dnuorgyalp!!!"
```

Comment: Can someone please elaborate on the matter of complexity of this approach?

Answer (score 2):

Working code!

```
 import UIKit

 var str = "Hello playground"

 let result = str.split(separator: " ").map { String($0.reversed())}.joined(separator: " ")
 print(result) // olleH dnuorgyalp
```

Comment: Good answer, but I'd like to see your analysis of the time complexity of your solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
let result = String(str.reversed())
    .components(separatedBy: .whitespaces)
    .reversed()
    .joined(separator: " ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on the OPs answer, if you wanted to follow English capitalization rules on the output:

```
var str = "Hello playground"

let result = str.split(separator: " ").enumerated().map {
    let reversed = String($0.1.reversed())
    return $0.0 == 0 ? reversed.capitalized : reversed.lowercased()
    }
    .joined(separator: " ")
print("Rerversing letters in each word = \"" + result + "\"") // Olleh dnuorgyalp
```

Also note that multiple spaces would mess this up, as would commas, periods, and other word/sentence delimiters.

Answer (score -1):

```
func FirstReverse(_ str: String) -> String {
  return String(str.reversed())
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30398209)